# Proper way to say "Traveler's Writ/Licence/Certificate"

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation, new-latin

I am looking for more or less the 'proper' (or any good approximation) way to translate a "Traveler's Writ," as in a certificate or license given to a traveler that allows him legal access to an area.

My problem is that there seems to be so many options for the concept of the 'writ' that I am not sure which way to go with this. Horrible old Goggle Translate gave me 'Charta viator est scriptor' but I feel that's terribly clunky. The era I am going for is 1500's Roman Catholic Latin.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thank you for a well thought and written question! Have you seen [this question about visas in Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/7565/79)? If it answers your question, we can mark your question as duplicate (which means making a permanent link so that people end up at the right place). If it doesn't, can you explain what's missing from your point of view?

Comment: med. L. *certification-em* (cited in the OED for [certification](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.99993/page/n244/mode/1up)) may be close enough. *certificatum* is not in L&S.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to [this visa question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/7565/79) gives several options for a document like this:

- *commeatus*
- *commeatus diploma*
- *commeatus syngraphus*
- *visa*

None of these is quoted as having a relation to your preferred era.
I'm not sure if any of these would be the official word, but I am pretty sure that these, especially *commeatus diploma*, would be understood.

As for the gibberish from Google Translate, I would translate *Charta viator est scriptor* as "paper traveller is writer".
This makes no sense — or if it does, I have hard time imagining it could be legitimately used to mean what you are after.
[Google Translate is not to be trusted with Latin.](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79)